# How can I create a log file in the RMI Server?

Tags: logging, rmi, sun

I'm currently working in the RMI server and I have added an algorithm to test it, my question is:

- How can I create then read a log file in the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Same way you do it in any other kind of system. You use your logging package of choice and write the code.

Comment: I haven't tried that before, is there any tutorial or example I can follow? because for my lake of experience my search didn't give me results.

Comment: @Evanescence Oh come off it. The JDK and the Java tutorial are chock full of examples. You should start by reading the Javadoc for java.util.logging.